# Changes in the Web API since the last update of the framework breaks my app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm using code like this

```
return new HttpResponseMessage
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
};
```

but since last update of MVC 4 or the Web Api libraries the response looks like this? http://cl.ly/Q6lK

If I use Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) it works great so what's the difference and why the sudden change in the framework?

Comment: Which new framework version are you referring too?  It looks like you are using a different version of the HttpResponseMessage class.

Comment: @DarrelMiller System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage is the correct class when using the ApiController and the exact same code worked fabulous before I upgraded the nuget packages.

Comment: Yes it is.  However, are you sure you are not referring to different versions of that assembly in different projects?  What you are doing should work just fine even in the latest version of Web API.

Comment: @DarrelMiller You are correct, my bad... sorry for your time.

Comment: No worries.  That's what SO is for :-)